# Verilog Mode - how to turn off colors for /* */ comments?

Tags: vim, comments, verilog

I am using vim to edit a customer's Verilog libmap file and the syntax highlighting for multi-line comments is causing very odd color enabling/disabling. The problem is that the libmap is searching large numbers of files in multiple directories so there are lots of `dir1/dir2/*/*/*/*/*.v` searches and each `/*` turns on comment colors and each corresponding `*/` turns it back off, so with all of the `libmap` wildcard directories the comments are turning on and off and sometimes remain off on the next active line of code.
I just want to know how to define (undefine) comment colors in Verilog mode. I will leave colors on for single line comments (`// comment`) but disable them for multi-line comments (`/* */`), which I rarely use, or perhaps change multi-line comments to require a space after `/*`.
I have snooped around the syntax definition file but cannot spot how the comments are being handled.
I am hoping this is relatively easy to do.
Regards - Cliff Cummings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, you don't want to "change colors", but to "change syntax". As patching standard runtime file is not an option, make use of `:h after-directory`.

> ~/.vim/after/syntax/verilog.vim

```
syntax clear verilogComment
" restore //comment
syntax match verilogComment "//.*" contains=verilogTodo,@Spell
" no /*comment*/
"syntax region verilogComment start="/\*" end="\*/" contains=verilogTodo,@Spell
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks! Is there a way to NOT add the //-comment when I open a newline beneath a comment? I find that to be exceptionally annoying